# changing Core Animation duration on ViewDidAppear doesn't seem to work

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, core-animation, calayer

I'm trying to have the iPad splash screen fade out to reveal my app's main interface over 2 secs. The main interface is my main view controller and view, inside a navigation controller.

So I did the following:

UINavigationController with my root view controller.
root view controller has its interface all laid out and, as a last step, a CALayer with the same png used for the splash screen covering the interface.

The idea is that once the real splash screen is gone, there's still the CALayer. And then I fade the CAlayer out to reveal the interface. It kind of works: the fade happens, but no matter what duration I set for the animation, it still happens too fast.

Here's the code: (logoLayer is an ivar and mainCanvas is a container view inside self.view, in which I insert most subviews -- for other screen-dim-type effects.)

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if (self) 
  {
        // Custom initialization

    self.view.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    [self setLayerContent:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"interfaceBackground" ofType:@"png"]];
    [self layoutNavigationButtonWithResource:@"button1" glowing:YES forAction:@"biblioteca"];
    [self layoutNavigationButtonWithResource:@"button2"glowing:YES forAction:@"portfolio"];

    NSString *logoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Default-Portrait~ipad" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:logoPath];
    logoLayer = [[CALayer layer] retain];
    logoLayer.contents = (id)image.CGImage;
    logoLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    logoLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    logoLayer.opacity = 1;
    [mainCanvas.layer addSublayer:logoLayer];
  }

  return self;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  [self performSelector:@selector(fadeOutLogo) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}

- (void)fadeOutLogo
{
  CABasicAnimation *a = [CABasicAnimation animation];
  a.duration = 10;
  [logoLayer addAnimation:a forKey:@"opacity"];
  [logoLayer setOpacity:0];
}
```

Notice I even delayed the call to the animation code just in case. And I also ended up with a value of 10sec. which is absurd for a fade. Still... the fade happens in about 0.2 secs.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That CABasicAnimation isn’t actually doing anything, because you’re not giving it a `fromValue` or `toValue`; when you’re setting the layer’s opacity, it’s only animating because setting properties on Core Animation layers triggers an implicit animation, whose default duration is about a quarter of a second. What you want to do is this:

```
- (void)fadeOutLogo
{
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:2];
    [logoLayer setOpacity:0];
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Comment: well, the explicit transaction surely would be another way of going about it. But my code above is still a valid way of momentarily overriding the layer's action dictionary and, other than for this situation when the main view is initialized, always works. Actually, the way I did it does implicitly create a transaction.

Comment: I just gave it a try and your suggestion does work. That's great! But.. any idea why mine doesn't? Meaning, I know your original answer. But am I wrong then that my code replaces the implicit action for @"opacity" in the layer's dictionary by setting a new duration and, when I call [logoLayer setOpacity:0] I'm implicitly animating with the new duration? I'd swear that's worked for me in the past

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, in viewWillAppear: you could instantiate a UIImageView with Default-Portrait~ipad.png, add it to self.view, use the UIView animateWithDuration:animations:completion: class method to animate the value of alpha to 0 over a period of 2 seconds, and then remove and release the UIImageView in the completion block. The following code demonstrates the idea, using a UIView instead of a UIImageView:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear: animated];
  UIView __block *fadeView = [[UIView alloc] 
  initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
  fadeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  [self.view addSubview: fadeView];
  [UIView animateWithDuration: 2 animations:^{
    fadeView.alpha = 0;
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
  fadeView = nil;
  }];
}
```